# Reflecting changes in a factory across the application

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, factory

So far I can get my application, from any point in the scope, to update a factory (DataStore-factory.js) and it's values.

DataStore-factory.js

```
return {
    storedValue: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 2
    },
    updateValue: function(value1, value2) {
        this.storedValue.val1 = value1;
        this.storedValue.val2 = value2;
    }
}
```

Controller that updates the value (Example-controller.js)

```
...
DataStoreFactory.updateValue(6,9);
$scope.dataVal = DataStoreFactory.storedValue
...
```

And how if I console.log out that value elsewhere in the application, it displays as 6 or 9 respectively. However on the view (Example-view.html) if I use

```
{{dataVal.val1}}
```

The value is not updated visually I update the Factory.

I have wrestled with this for so long that a fresh pair of eyes might be what this needs. As a side addendum I'd like to request any sources on the internet that maybe you used to specifically understand why the above scenario is not working and what I need to learn to avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't update because, in your controller, you are making an affectation. You have to bind instead if you want the refresh data.

On your dataStore :

```
return {
    storedValue: {
        val1: 1,
        val2: 2
    },
    updateValue: function(value1, value2) {
        this.storedValue.val1 = value1;
        this.storedValue.val2 = value2;
    },
    getStoredValue : function(){
       return storedValue;
    }
}
```

And then in your controller :

```
DataStoreFactory.updateValue(6,9);
$scope.getDataVal = DataStoreFactory.getStoredValue;
```

After that you can get the value this way :

```
var val1 = $scope.getDataVal().val1;
var val2 = $scope.getDataVal().val2;
```

You can also use this syntax in your HTML :

```
{{getDataVal().val1}}
```

With this, you will have the updated value in your controller/View

Comment: So, if I change the value of `this.storedValue.val1` elsewhere, this should reflect here or will an additional 'refresh' sort of function be required?

Comment: On your DOM it will be done directly. The value is only store in your factory, your Controller is binding on it, and then your DOM is binding on it too.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, It does seem like that would be the correct solution semantically as well (the factory looks nicer like that instead of talking directly to arrays and stuff)